# Add API to Angular and ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2022

I'm starting with the "Angular and ASP.NET Core" project template in Visual Studio 2022. It starts with a "WeatherForecastController" as an example ApiController which works fine. If I go to the URL in the browser "https://localhost:4200/weatherforecast" I can see the JSON in the response.

When I try to add another API "FooController" or "TestController" for example and navigate to that URL in the browser, instead of the expected JSON, I get the Angular index.html page and a note in the browser console saying "Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'".

Even stranger if I try adding "WeatherForecast**2**Controller", that **does ** work. In fact, any URL starting with "WeatherForecast" will either work, or return a 404 as I expected. Every other URL seems to return index.html.

How do I add a new API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that **Angular** routing is totally different from **.Net core** API routing.

---

.NET CORE API controller can be reach via `/api/YourControllName` in your browser.

If you want to reach your FooController API, you need to visit `localhost:[iisport]/api/Foo`

---

For Angular, you need to create a new route attached to a component in your `app-routing.module` like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'weatherforecast', component: WeatherForecastComponent },
{ path: 'fooPage', component: FooComponent },
]
```

Comment: Using /api/ doesn't help. Adding it just returns the index.html page.

Comment: Yes i was explaining the difference, but if you want to navigate to another URL/route on your angular application, you need to create another